# Variance of largest eigenvector of bounded random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-variables

Given a random $n\times n$ bounded positive semidefinite matrix $X$ with $\mathbb{E}[X]=A$ and some constant matrix $B$, define an estimator $\hat{o} = tr[BX^T]$ with $\mathbb{E}[\hat{o}] = \mu$ and $\mbox{Var}[\hat{o}] = \sigma^2$. We immediately have that

$$
\mu = tr[BA] \quad \mbox{and} \quad \sigma^2 = \mathbb{E}[tr[BX^T]^2] - \mu^2
$$

Now pick up the eigenvalue ordering for the variable $X$ as $1 \geq \lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \dots \lambda_n \geq 0$ and define the vector $v$ $(vv^T = 1)$ such that $Xv = \lambda_1 v$ i.e. the first eigenvector of $X$. What can be said about the variance $\mbox{Var}[tr[Bvv^T]]$ of this eigenvector estimator in terms of $X, \mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[tr[BX^T]^2]$?

I am mostly interested in upper bounds on the eigenvector estimator variance but do not know how to even begin to treat this when I am considering eigenvectors of a random matrix $X$ as a starting point, rather than $v$ as the random variable itself. Since $X$ is promised to be positive definite it seems like taking the eigendecomposition of $X$ might yield an upper bound similar to $ \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda_1^2} $ but this seems rather weak. Any help as to where to begin would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *in terms of $X$*? $X$ is random and so is a bound depending on $X$.

Comment: Indeed, that was poor phrasing. I mean a bound that relates to the properties of $X$, meaning $\mathbb{E}[X], \mbox{Var}[X]$.